# PrimeFaces RequestContext update

Tags: primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 6 and wanted to update all `datatable`s from a Bean. Therefore I tried

`RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("@(.ui-datatable)");`

this does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: What **does** it do? Start WW3? Did you inspect the network traffic? Are ID's to be updated send from the client to the server? Lots of simple things you can find out

Answer (score 1):

I think this could work. To update all datatables, simply call `updateDatatable(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot())`.

```
public void updateDatatable(UIComponent root) {
    if (root != null) {
        if (root instanceof DataTable) {
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(root.getClientId());
        } else {
            for (UIComponent c : root.getChildren()) {
                this.updateDatatable(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```